# Adding Light to Existing 3-Way Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I have a poorly lit hallway with 3-way wiring setup as shown in the image below:

[image]

I want to add an additional light in the position shown below and can't figure out if it's possible or not. The wire is already running where I want to add the light.

[image]

Is this possible, and if so, which wires would I connect to the light? Would of course add a junction box but just want to avoid running any new wire if I can.

If not possible, can I wire it just from the first switch on the left? That would be an easier new wire to run than from the second switch / existing light.

TIA

Comment: Are smart-switches an option for you?\

Comment: no it is not possible without running a wire

Comment: Smart switches unfortunately not an option

Comment: @Ruskes do you know if I could wire it just from first switch? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but will only go on/off with that switch, not a 3 way. chose any travelers as your hot, then add neutral to the light.

Comment: Why are smart switches not an option? Smart switches do **not** have to mean WiFi or internet or Alexa or remote access.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact sorry I misunderstood then - sure I can use a smart switch if it doesn’t involve wifi. What kind of switch is this exactly?

Answer (score 4):

Everyone who asks this question wants the same thing.  They want to be able to wire the new light **off a switch**.

That is not possible unless you know the switch wiring intimately AND you get lucky.  I have found that people who say "my wiring is EXACTLY like this diagram I found on the Internet" are often mistaken.

The upshot is that the only safe play is to tap the new light off the existing light.

If you can find one of the switches, and confirm that this is indeed the cable that goes directly to the existing light, you can tap it there.

As far as intercepting an existing cable, you have a couple of problems.  First, the wires that you need *are simply Not There*.   And second, you can't physically tap a cable like that. Any splice needs to be inside a junction box, and junction boxes need at least 6" of slack wire length in the box, so that is not going to happen unless the builder left you *over a foot* of slack.  And builders don't do that.  *You can't do one of those deals where you reach deep into the box with your fingers, pinch the wires together "just so" and barely slip on a wire nut. That does not create a safe or maintainable connection.  The only option in such a case is to have 2 junction boxes at least a foot apart, and nobody wants that, since those junction boxes must remain accessible and can't be buried*.

Other than that, your only option is to go with "smart switches". In this case you re-wire the circuit so that black and white are always-hot and neutral (to both smart switches), red is switched-hot (from one smart switch), and the switches communicate either power-line communication or via radio, such as Insteon units do. Then you can do what you want, presuming you can solve the "wire length in junction box" problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with doing what you want is there is no switched hot between the two switch boxes, only travelers (which are only controlled by the first switch).

Your only choices are to either add a new 2-wire (plus ground) cable from the second switch box to the new light, or use smart switches. The smart switches do not need to be remote controllable, only that they require only a single traveler. This would allow you to re-use the red-wire in the cable running between the switches as a switched got to the new light.

Comment: Got it thank you! Re smart switches, I would presumably need to replace both switches? Or how would I do this?

Comment: That’s correct: same brand and series. Sometimes, you’ll get a smart switch and a “remote” switch. The remaining traveler is used both to pass power and a control signal between the switches.